# raw hard disk acces /dev/sd[x] vs /dev/sg[y]?

Tags: c, linux, io, hard-drive, scsi

I have been working on a program which reads data from harddisks. And I wonder is it better to use the sda device or the sg0 device? I understand that sg0 is better used if you are gonna do things like use the sg driver for such things as inquirys etc but I want to read data from the drive... Another difference is that sg0 is a character device and sda is a block device

Comment: This is OS specific. If this is a Linux question, please add a Linux tag.

Answer (score 1):

The /dev/sda is a block device - you can open it from your C program by [open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open), then read/write/seek/pread/pwrite (regular Linux I/O functions!) it, then close it.

The "sg" driver is a more intelligent and more uniform way to access storage devices - you need to form a SCSI command to send something to the device via the "sg" driver and you need to parse the message it will send you back.

For more info please look [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/what.html).